# Text keeps wrapping inside the web page width, preventing me from doing a complete scrolling marquee

Tags: javascript, css, xml

I am trying to do a News bar reading from XML file, I could be able to have the reading from XML file method and sending it to a moving tag, thing is the showing text would not exceed the width of the website like shown here
http://www.leeandmao.com/Message_Crawler/

The XML file http://www.leeandmao.com/Message_Crawler/xml/rss-topstories.xml

I want it to keep on going like one line and not being bounded by the page width

The code:

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          myFunction(this);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "/Message_Crawler/xml/rss-topstories.xml", true);
      xhttp.send();
    
    function myFunction(xml) {
      var i;
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      var table="";
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
      for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
        table += 
        "&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;"+ x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + ":"+"&emsp;"+ x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      
      }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
     
    }
```

```css
.marquee {
     height: 50px; 
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
     background: yellow;
     color: black;
     font-size:1em;
     border: 2px solid black;
    
    }
    .marquee p {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     line-height: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     /* Starting position */
     -moz-transform:translateX(100%);
     -webkit-transform:translateX(100%); 
     transform:translateX(100%);
     /* Apply animation to this element */ 
     -moz-animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
     -webkit-animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
     animation: scroll-left 15s linear infinite;
    }
    /* Move it (define the animation) */
    @-moz-keyframes scroll-left {
     0%   { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
     100% { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes scroll-left {
     0%   { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
     100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
    }
    @keyframes scroll-left {
     0%   { 
     -moz-transform: translateX(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
     -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); /* Browser bug fix */
     transform: translateX(100%);   
     }
     100% { 
     -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
     -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); /* Browser bug fix */
     transform: translateX(-100%); 
     }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="marquee">
    <p id="demo">Click me to change my HTML content (innerHTML).</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: If you see XML, there are loads of titles and description, while its not showing except 3 or 2 depending on the web page width, I want it showing all titles and descriptions in the xml